# OOP Inheritance homework (Animal to lion super class inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance

I need to:
Extend the animal class with a Lion class and have different features(done).

Add a field called Liontype class and add a method classifying the lion type per its weight.(Needs to be derived from the superclass)

And print it out.

There are errors in my code and I've been trying to fix it.
Thank for any assistance in advance.

```
public class Animal {
  private int numTeeth = 0;
  private boolean spots = false;
  private int weight = 0;

  public Animal(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight){
    this.setNumTeeth(numTeeth);
    this.setSpots(spots);
    this.setWeight(weight);
  }

  public int getNumTeeth(){
    return numTeeth;
  }

  public void setNumTeeth(int numTeeth) {
    this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
  }

  public boolean getSpots() {
    return spots;
  }

  public void setSpots(boolean spots) {
    this.spots = spots;
  }

  public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
  }

  public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
  }
}

//Extend animal class
 public class Lion extends Animal{
  public Lion (int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight){
  super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
  //Add new attributes
    int age = 0;
    int cubs = 0;
  }

 public static void main(String args[]){
   //Create lions and assign attributes
   Lion lion1 = new Lion();
   lion1.numTeeth = 12;
   lion1.spots = 1;
   lion1. weight = 86;
   lion1.age = 7;
   lion1.cubs = 3;

    //Print attributes
    System.out.println("Lion1 attributes:");
    System.out.println("Number of teeth : " + numTeeth);
    System.out.println("Number of spots : " + spots);
    System.out.println("Weight of lion : " + weight + " kgs");
    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("No of cubs : " + cubs);
    System.out.println(" ");

   Lion lion2 = new Lion();
   lion2.numTeeth = 16;
   lion2.spots = 0;
   lion2. weight = 123;
   lion2.age = 13;
   lion2.cubs = 5;

    System.out.println("Lion2 attributes:");
    System.out.println("Number of teeth : " + numTeeth);
    System.out.println("Number of spots : " + spots);
    System.out.println("Weight of lion : " + weight + " kgs");
    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("No of cubs : " + cubs);
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public class Liontype{
  //Trying to get weight from another class
  public Integer getWeight()
  {
    if (weight > 120)
    {
      System.out.println("This lion is a cub");
    }
    else if (weight >= 120 && weight < 180)
    {
      System.out.println("This lion is a female");
    }
    else if (weight >= 180)
    {
      System.out.println("This lion is a male");
    }
  }
}
}


Expected outcome:

Lion attributes:
Number of teeth : 16
Spots : true
Weight of lion : 83kgs
Age : 13
No of cubs : 3
This lion is a female
```

Comment: what errors ? compiler or runtime? please be specific

Comment: Where is the `LionType` resp. `Lion`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to errors pointed out by Dmitry, your `main` in  the `Lion` class has the following:

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
   //Create lions and assign attributes
   Lion lion1 = new Lion();
   lion1.numTeeth = 12;
   lion1.spots = 1;
   lion1. weight = 86;
   lion1.age = 7;
   lion1.cubs = 3;
```

`numTeeth` `spots` `weight` and all the other fields are set private. Your `Lion` class can't access these fields directly. You are supposed to use your getters and setters you from the `Animal`

Also when printing attributes in `Lion`:

```
 //Print attributes
    System.out.println("Lion1 attributes:");
    System.out.println("Number of teeth : " + numTeeth);
    System.out.println("Number of spots : " + spots);
    System.out.println("Weight of lion : " + weight + " kgs");
    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("No of cubs : " + cubs);
    System.out.println(" ");
```

your fields are attributes to an object. Trying to print the fields directly will give you an compiler error because those are properties of your `Lion1` object. You need to use the dot operator like this:

```
System.out.println("Number of Teeth" + Lion1.getNumTeeth());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many problems in your code that will be obtained at the compilation stage. Perhaps you incorrectly specified your examples. So, please provide details of your problem.

I will point out some that are immediately evident:

1. You declared local variables

   int age = 0;
   int cubs = 0;

in the constructor that doesn't actually extend the class `Lion` with new attributes. Add these attributes as a fields as you did to the class `Animal`:

```
private int age = 0;
private int cubs = 0;
```

and then initialize them in the constructor of the class `Lion` (if necessary).

2. In the method `public static void main(String args[])`, you are trying to use 
   `Lion` class fields `age, cubs` that it does not have. See point 1.
3. The `public Integer getWeight()` of the class `Liontype` has 2 errors. Firstly, the variable `weight` is not defined, and secondly there is missing the return statement, although the method must return a `Integer` value.